# svg2png on Heroku - TypeError: Bad argument

Tags: node.js, heroku, promise

I have a problem with svg2png package on Heroku. It works on my machine locally (Windows), but I can't get it working neither on free dyno, nor paid ones (both Hobby and Standard x1).

The idea is to get svg from Wikipedia and return it as png. I've exposed two endpoints:

- / - that uses code stored in separated file,
- /simple - same code, but just in the callback.

When browsing both endpoints I receive Heroku Application error page. That's what I get in Heroku logs for both requests:

```
Bad argument TypeError: Bad argument
 at exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
 at Object.execFile (/app/node_modules/pn/_promisify.js:35:27)
 at TypeError (native)
 at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:294:26)
 at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:143:15)
 at Promise.resolve.then (/app/node_modules/svg2png/lib/svg2png.js:13:33)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Do you have an idea?

**index.js**

```
const svg2png = require('svg2png')
const axios = require('axios')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const conv = require('./conv')

const svgUrl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg'

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'5mb'}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true,limit:'5mb'}))

app.get('/simple', function (req, res) {
    axios.get(svgUrl)
        .then(response => {
            return svg2png(response.data, { width: 150, height: 150 })
        })
        .then(pngFile => {
            var img = new Buffer(pngFile, 'base64')
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'image/png',
     'Content-Length': img.length
            })
            res.end(img)
        })
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
conv.send()    
        .then(pngFile => {
            var img = new Buffer(pngFile, 'base64')
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'image/png',
     'Content-Length': img.length
            })
            res.end(img)
        })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function () {
    console.log('Application started')
})
```

**conv.js**

```
const axios = require('axios')
const svg2png = require('svg2png')

module.exports = {
    send() {
        const self = this;
                self.width = 300;
        self.height = 300;

        const svgUrl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg'
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get(svgUrl)
            .then(response => 

            svg2png(response.data,
             { width: self.width, height: self.height })
            .then(img=>resolve(img))
            .catch(e => {
                console.log('Something went wrong during svg2png conversion.' + e)
                reject(e)
            }))
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Do the Heroku logs have any more information about which line might be causing the `TypeError`? That'll make it easier to track down where the problem is.

Comment: @bouteillebleu, I've updated the post, pasting full error message. When I played with logging from catch() methods, I've found the problem was in svg2png (assuming I proprerly chained promise methods...).